# Typescript - Type an Interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, typescript-typings

My apologies if this is a bit vague as I am not 100% on typescript. Is there a way to add a typing to an interface?

Tech: Angular 9, Swagger, and TypeScript.

This being wrong, but something like this:

```
export interface PasswordRequest: components["schemas"]["PasswordRequest"] {}
```

And I am not looking for:

```
export interface PasswordRequest {
  email?: string | null;
  oldPassword?: string | null;
}
```

It's a long story, but basically swagger is being retrofitted into old app. It spits out

```
    export interface components { schemas: { PasswordRequest: { email?: string | null; oldPassword?: string | null; newPassword?: string | null; };
with all the needed interface under this components > schemas structure.
```

I am trying to avoid ripping/renaming interfaces and all the imports.

Comment: What do you mean by "type an interface"? An interface in itself *is* a type you can apply to things.

Comment: I'm not clear what your goal is. Do you want to start with the type found at `components["schemas"]["PasswordRequest"]`, then tweak it to create a new type?

Comment: @NicholasTower  It's a long story, but basically swagger is being retro fitted into old app. 
 It spits out 'export interface components {
  schemas: {
    PasswordRequest: {
      email?: string | null;
      oldPassword?: string | null;
      newPassword?: string | null;
    };'  I am trying to avoid ripping/renaming interfaces and all the imports.

Comment: If you just want to be able to refer to it by the name `PasswordRequest`, then you can  do `export type PasswordRequest = components["schemas"]["PasswordRequest"]`. If that's not what you mean, then i'll still need some more details on what your goal is

Comment: @NicholasTower ...I think that might be what I need.

Comment: Give a look in advanced types in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you use a type to extract the relevant piece of the interface

```
export type PasswordRequest  = components['schemas']['PasswordRequest']
```